# how to use inputdlg with for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

have tried searching but can't find anything to help, maybe my problem is too simple!  Anyway, I'm running a nested FOR loop, but the array I save my results to only keeps the last "run" of results. Can someone please help me to store/concatenate the results ?

```
clc 
clear
n = 2;
for aa = 1:n
aa = inputdlg({'Depth from','Depth to','Outer Diameter','Nominal Weight'},'1',[1 7;1 7;1 30;1 30]);
x = [str2num(aa{1}),str2num(aa{2}),str2num(aa{3}),str2num(aa{4})]
end
```

and the results 
x =

```
 1     2     3     4
```

x =

```
 5     6     7     8
```

I cannot use the first one, 
want to save all the results and save every iteration in a single variable

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to save the result into an array in a for loop; separate the looping variable and the array you are storing values in:

```
clc 
clear
n = 2;
x = zeros(n, 4);
for k = 1:n
    aa = inputdlg({'Depth from','Depth to','Outer Diameter','Nominal Weight'},'1',[1 7;1 7;1 30;1 30]);
    x(k, :) = [str2double(aa{1}),str2double(aa{2}),str2double(aa{3}),str2double(aa{4})];
end
```

Then if you display x you get something like:

```
x =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
```

Assuming you entered 1 to 4 and then 5 to 8 in the dialog.